# Is $K:=\{u\in X|\int_0^1|u(t)|^2dt<1\}$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X:=C([0,1];\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $||u||_\infty:=sup_{t\in[0,1]}|u(t)|$. Also let $K:=\{u\in X|\int_0^1|u(t)|^2dt<1\}$
>
> Show that K is convex, symmetric, $0\in K$. And show if K is bounded.

I already showed the convexity and that K is symmetric and contains $0$. But I have no idea how I would find a boundary for K. Can someone help me?

Comment: If $u \in C([0,1])$ with $\|u \|_\infty > 1$, would we have $u \in K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the familly of functions defined by

$$\left\{ \begin{array} 
.f_n(x) = \frac{n-n^2x}{2} &  0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \\
f_n(x) = 0 &  \frac{1}{n^2} \leq x
\end{array} \right.$$

$\| f_n \|_\infty = \frac{n}{2} \to +\infty$ but $f_n \in K$ :

$$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2 dx = 1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2} - \frac{1}{n} < 1$$

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question before. I thought we were talking about the $L^2$ norm, but we are not. Apologies.